# Hyperledger new consortium

Tags: channel, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Is it possible to create a brand new consortium after an orderer has started with the genesis block? If yes, how?
The documentation has example of updating a channel regarding to an existing consortium but I can find nothing related to creating a new consortium.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Could you please specify a use case?  You can extend an existing consortium, why would you need to create a new one?

Comment: @ArtemBarger in case we want to add new consortium for a new supply chain? How do you extend an existing consortium? Could you please explain it in more details? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think your use case can be satisfied by creating a new channel among organizations than creating a new consortium. Chaincode can be programmed in such way that other organizations will not be getting access to data in a particular chain.